# Winforms Thread Application Hang (background worker Thread)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have build application using VS 2010 , C#.

I am using `BackgroundWorker` in my application.

While I click on button code getting records from database and showing into Datagrid. 
but the problem is while I running it from code it's working fine but when I running program .exe so it's being hang.

```
//Declared delegate
delegate void SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(Control control, string propertyName, object propertyValue);

//Declared method to run control Thread safe
public static void SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(Control control, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {   
        control.Invoke(new SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(SetControlPropertyThreadSafe), new object[] { control, propertyName, propertyValue });
    }
    else
    {              
        control.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, control, new object[] { propertyValue });
    }
}


//calling method like below
SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(dataGridView1, "DataSource", dtGrid2);
```

I don't understand where I done mistake.
why the program is hanging ?

Comment: Attach a debugger to the hung application and "break" it. That should show you here it is "hung".

Comment: but while I running it in debug mode it's not hung

Comment: I said "Attach a debugger **to the hung application**", not run it in debug. VS can connect to most apps or thread for debugging purposes.

Comment: oh ok.. sorry I don't know this.. can you please help me how can I attach debugger ?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 express

Comment: `Debug` menu - `Attach to process` is the usual. Not sure if the express editions have all the options. Please check.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx

Comment: @SriramSakthivel .. Thanks.. but I am using express edition which doesnot have this facility :(

Comment: I don't understand what the code you posted is for, or how it relates to the problem at hand. The code you posted is for a delegate control class. What does this have to do with `BackgroundWorker`? `BackgroundWorker` exposes events for you so you DON'T NEED delegation.

Comment: @Shaamaan.. delegate is required to call Thread safe. `SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(dataGridView1, "DataSource", dtGrid2);` is running under `Backgroundworker_DoWork()` .. while my application running I need to show the output on Main window.

Comment: Take a dump of your process using [`procdump`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) and analyze it with [`WinDbg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're using `BackgroundWorker`... wrong.

The `BackgroundWorker` class allows you to perform an operation in the background, provide information to the UI about progress and finally return a complete result.

As the OP states:

> delegate is required to call Thread safe. `SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(dataGridView1, "DataSource", dtGrid2);` is running under Backgroundworker_DoWork() .. while my application running I need to show the output on Main window.

You're not supposed to update the UI from the `DoWork` method manually. If you must update the UI in any fashion, you can use the `ProgressChanged` event available on the `BackgroundWorker` class and call `ReportProgress` during the execution of `DoWork`. Also make sure to set `WorkerReportsProgress` to true.

The `ReportProgress` method is flexible enough to allow you to pass almost anything back to the UI if you must (the `ProgressChangedEventArgs` class contains a `UserState` object property which you can use to pass any kind of data you want). Check the example code given on [`BackgroundWorker` MSND page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's my example:

```
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

    void StartBackgroundTask()
    {
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        //if it's possible to display progress, use this
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        //what to do when the method finishes?
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        //start!
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //perform any "finalization" operations, like re-enable disabled buttons
        //display the result using the data in e.Result
        //this code will be running in the UI thread
    }

    //example of a container class to pass more data in the ReportProgress event
    public class ProgressData
    {
        public string OperationDescription { get; set; }
        public int CurrentResult { get; set; }
        //feel free to add more stuff here
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //display the progress using e.ProgressPercentage or e.UserState
        //this code will be running in the UI thread
        //UserState can be ANYTHING:
        //var data = (ProgressData)e.UserState;
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //this code will NOT be running in the UI thread!
        //you should NOT call the UI thread from this method

        int result = 1;
        //perform calculations
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(i, new ProgressData(){ OperationDescription = "CustomState passed as second, optional parameter", CurrentResult = result });
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            result *= i;
        }

        e.Result = result;
    }
```

Unless you **must** display the already loaded elements to the user while still loading them, then you should use `ReportProgress` to display just that - progress. Use the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to finally pass the results to the UI.

If you use your own UI-updating delegates, then you might as well ditch `BackgroundWorker` altogether and use a `Task` instead.

Comment: @Shaamaan .. how can I update my datagridview with this method ?. I have return below code but it does not helped me

Comment: `int output = 1;`  
`backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(output, dtGrid2);`  
`//SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(dataGridView1, "DataSource", dtGrid2);`    `private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           // progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = e;
        }`

Comment: Ok I think it's have to write like this (it's working for me right now) but I still digging if I am missing anything..

Comment: `private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           // progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)e.UserState;
        }`

Comment: now I am wondering we can pass only one value to progresschanged  ? I have  many labels and progressbar and Datagridview in UI thread so how can I able to synchronize them all with the same way ?

Comment: @Hardik You can pass one object, yes, but that object can be as complicated as you wish. You could create a "container" object to hold all the progress-related values, and pass that using the `UserState` property.

Answer (score 5):

```
  void SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(...)
```

There's a Big Problem with methods like this.  Unfortunately very hard to root out, there are *way* too many posts on SO that recommend this.  The problem is that it lulls a programmer to sleep, it is "safe" so surely it is not the cause of the problem.  Turning a problem into an undebuggable issue.

There is absolutely nothing "safe" about it:

- Using Control.Invoke() is *dangerous*, it is very prone to cause deadlock.  Triggered when there's code in the UI thread that does something unwise like waiting for the worker thread to complete.  Only use Invoke() when you have your back to the wall, actually requiring the return value.  And when you find out *that's* necessary then don't do it, it always races unless you disable the UI.  Always use BeginInvoke() instead.
- It hides a *fire-hose* problem.  You'll be lulled into calling the method to update every single control and not thinking about the problem that this causes.  Which is pummeling the UI thread with the invoke requests.  Do this at a rate ~50 times higher than the human eye can see and you'll bury the UI thread.  It can never catch up with the invoke requests, as soon as it dispatched one then there's another one waiting to be executed.  The UI thread now stops taking care of its normal duties, like painting windows and handling user input.  It looks *frozen*, just like it would if you ran this code directly
- Very unpleasant things happen when the user closes the window but your worker thread keeps motoring.  Invoking to a window that no longer exists.  This *usually* gives a loud bang so isn't too hard to diagnose.  Sometimes it doesn't, impossible to debug, there is an inevitable threading race between stopping the thread and allowing the window to close, one that can only be solved by not closing the window but hiding it instead.

Your problem is the second bullet.  It hangs because your code is running faster now.  The Invoke() call hid the problem in the debugger.  Get rid of this code completely, it is **dangerous**, and gather results from the dbase query in, say, a List<>.  Pass it to the ReportProgress() method, once in a while so you don't hose the UI thread.  Re-create the List after the call so it is thread-safe.